# Possible to find traffic sources for popular question I asked?

Tags: feature-request, support

I [recently asked a question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/264869/what-is-this-shadow-being-cast-upon) on the Physics SE site that ended up being fairly popular.  After 2 days it already has over 3,000 views.

Over the years I've occasionally asked other questions where this has happened and I'm always curious where the inbound traffic is coming from.  From what I can tell, questions don't get this number of views unless someone links to them externally.

Is there any way to view where viewers are coming from?  If not - would this be a feature worth adding?  I think a lot of people might find it interesting.

Comment: Questions can get pretty popular from being on the Hot Network Posts alone.

Comment: Questions can also get more views when they're posted on Meta

Comment: Can you do this with the data explorer?

Comment: @Glo [That's an answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7vZSa.jpg), why not post it?

Comment: @Glorfindel is correct, however since there is no added querystring parameter to the HNQ links, it's impossible to be 100% sure as the data is not really stored anywhere. The "dry fact" answer to the question is that it's not possible to find the traffic sources, only guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to see this for an entire site, not a particular question. If you have the *Access To Site Analytics* privilege, you can see this dashboard:

> [image: site analytics]

This has some useful information about the inbound traffic. This information is not available through SEDE, and I don't think it should, at least not on a too detailed level, since it can point back to specific users eventually.

I am wondering if such a dashboard can be useful on a tag or question level, but I don't feel much for it. I doubt whether this is really useful.

Most of the time, such new posts with high views are on the Hot Network Questions list, or was tweeted by the SE Twitter bot. [Yours was in the HNQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vZSa.jpg), as nicael commented, so probably that is the reason for the number of views.